# Castle Windsor Namespace conflicts

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, castle-windsor

Say I'm working inside a namespace called, for example, `Org.Company` and that this namespace contains `MyClass`.
I'm also importing a nuget with a namespace called `Company` with a class named `OtherClass`.

So, when I'm working inside my `Org.Company` namespace, I can't do the following:

`Company.OtherClass obj;`

because the compiler assumes that I actually mean:

`Org.Company.Otherclass obj`

which doesn't exist.

So, as far as I know, instead of using the fully qualified name, I actually MUST import the other namespace as such `using Company;`

The problem, however, is that I need to reference this `OtherClass` **from a XML file** (Castle Windsor configuration file) and the fully qualified name `Company.OtherClass` isn't working.
Is there a way around this? Changing namespace names isn't a viable option.

**EDIT:**
This is what I have on my Castle Windsor xml file

```
<using assembly="MyProj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
...
<component
  service="Company.IOtherClass"
  type="Company.OtherClass"
  />
```

I get the following error:

`{"Could not convert string 'Company.OtherClass' to a type. Make sure assembly containing the type has been loaded into the process, or consider specifying assembly qualified name of the type."}`

Probably because its looking inside `Org.Company` instead, defined in the `MyProj` assembly.

I assume this could be fixed if there was a way to add another `<using />` statement referencing the Nuget package... Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does Castle Windsor return any error meesage? Or can you maybe use fully qualified name, including assembly, in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem is about referencing from XML? Right?

So as Castle.Windsor suggests "consider specifying assembly qualified name of the type.". What does it mean? It means that instead of:

```
<component
    service="Company.IOtherClass"
    type="Company.OtherClass"
/>
```

You should give class names with assembly they are coming from:

```
<component
    service="Company.IOtherClass, OtherClassAssembly"
    type="Company.OtherClass, OtherClassAssembly"
/>
```

or even fully qualified assembly name:

```
<component
    service="Company.IOtherClass, OtherClassAssembly, Version=..., Culture=..., PublicKeyToken=..."
    type="Company.OtherClass, OtherClassAssembly, Version=..., Culture=..., PublicKeyToken=..."
/>
```

**NOTE**: replace OtherClassAssembly with actual assembly name and DON'T add .dll extension here
**NOTE**: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx for more details, for example how to deal with nested classes

To use OtherClass in code, well, you can use global

```
global::Company.OtherClass
```

you can also use using:

```
using Company;
```

or just import one class:

```
using ClassFromOtherCompany = Company.OtherClass;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I ended up simply adding another `using assembly` node as such: `<using assembly="Company" />`. I had no idea I could use this to import already compiled dlls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespace alias, something like this MSDN example:

```
using Co = Company.Proj.Nested;
```

Comment: But since he mentioned that he needs to do it in XML, alias does not seem to be valid option

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging from the description of the problem and the error message you're getting it would appear your suspicion is correct.

The assembly from Nuget package hasn't been loaded into the AppDomain by the time Windsor runs its installers, so it has no way of knowing where to get the `Company.OtherClass` from.

You can then either do as the error message suggests, and use assembly qualified type name, or preload the assembly, with `<using />` tag.